# I couldn't run my simple android app which I created using Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

[image]I can't build and run my app.. cause when I run my app it shows some weird errors I'm not aware of.. please help me out. What should I do?

I tried implement "optional classes" through the error log

my IDE shows me to create a lot of optional classes in the error log, but it won't stop

Comment: *it shows some weird errors* no, it doesn't, the error is pretty clear

Comment: Try to learn how to read the error log. Those lots of optional classes are part of stack trace.

Comment: I'm so sorry for asking a dull quenstion like this. but I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 2):

'S' in String/enter_a_number is in capital case. Make it small. It should be

```
string/enter_a_number
```

Answer (score 2):

Open strings.xml file and search for `enter_a_number`.
You will found two result. Remove any one of them. And run app.

Comment: all the errors gone.. I fixed them all and thank you @ezio